# Bones getting left behind in mesh transform

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, vertices

[image][enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/avkv9ls51q4x9e5/sheet%20fold%201.blend?dl=0)I have just taken the plunge into bones animation and having all sorts of problems.
I want to animate 3 seperate folds on each side of a sheet, without using a mirror modifier. 
The first fold of the white triangle on each side of the sheet is not a problem. However when I try to fold the "**half_full_R**" bone, the bone "**wing_R**" gets left behind. Also I am not sure which vertice to assign to the "**half_part_R**" bone or whether there is any specific parenting or other settings to do to make this work.
I have attached a final render showing the result of the folds.
Any help with this would be appreciated.
Link to blend file below:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/avkv9ls51q4x9e5/sheet%20fold%201.blend?dl=0
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please share your file?

Comment: I have just added the link to my file in my original post.

Comment: so, first thing, why do you make one armature per bone and not one armature with all your bones? You should join them all

Comment: Im new to bones and not sure how it all works.

Comment: So maybe follow some tutorials about bones and rigging, no reason not to make one single armature for the whole thing

Comment: All tutorials I have come accross are on character rigging which makes it difficult to relate to my setup.

Comment: You have simpler tutorials, what you need is to have one root bone, then bones that are children of this one and that will control the wings...

Comment: Can you modify my file to show what you mean?

Comment: all the Blender foundation basic tutorials are good to begin with

Comment: Great, thanks for your help.

Comment: I'll try to rig your object if I've got time (or someone else here maybe)

Comment: Ok thanks, that will be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you could do is:

- First, to clean a bit, remove the current armature and the object *Armature* modifier.

[image]

- Also, delete all the existing vertex groups.

[image]

- Prepare the right side of the armature, each bone must be the child of another one, the main one is the root bone. Put their head on the paper fold so that it will fold correctly. Give them some logical names fold Wing1_R, etc... Once you're good, select them all and in the header menu select *Armature* > *Symmetrize*, it will mirror your bones (as long as they have the R or L suffix).

[image]

- Parent the paper to the armature With Empty Groups, which means some vertex groups will be created within the object, they will have the name of the bones, but they won't be affected to any bone yet. It's the best way to parent as your object is not organic.

[image]

- Now select some vertices and in the *Vertex Groups* list, assign them to the group to which there are supposed to be part of, meaning which have the name of the bone that is supposed to influence them.

[image]

Blend file here: [image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101280/discussion-on-answer-by-moonboots-bones-getting-left-behind-in-mesh-transform).